# Reading data from a socket in ruby in a multithreaded environment

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to read an HTTP packet via a socket in ruby, and for some reason my code keeps on blocking whilst calling recv

```
socket = TCPSocket.new("localhost",80)
socket.send r.join("\r\n"), 0
socket.flush
#We're only interested in the string "HTTP/1.1 XXX"
if http_status = get_http_status(socket.recv_nonblock(12))
    if http_status == 200
        $logger.info "Wrote #{message_packet}"
    else
        $logger.warn "Resubmitting message because #{line} is not 200"
        @queue.publish(message) 
    end
end

#Get rid of the rest of the content
the_rest = socket.recv(1000)
while(the_rest != "") do
    the_rest = socket.recv(1000)    
end
```

From what I understand of `recv` it should return nothing if there's no data waiting on the socket?

Comment: This question is very badly written and missing some very important data that actually makes this question make any sense. The code is also wrong. Please close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection could be a keep-alive connection. So, your recv() call wont end by itself. You will need to read the Content-Lenght header, then do a read of that many bytes from the content. After that you can get out of the RECV loop.

Or alternately, issue the request by setting "Connection: close" header so that the server closes the connection after sending the response.